# I'm facing a Rust issue: "error: failed to run custom build command for 'zstd-sys v2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5'". How can I resolve this problem?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm developing a Rest API project using Rust (version 1.75.0) and Actix web (version 4.4.1). During compilation, I encounter the error 'error: failed to run custom build command for zstd-sys v2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5.' Surprisingly, when I switch to Actix web version 3.3.3, the compilation succeeds. This is the error output :

```
C:/Users/bolingo/.cargo/bin/cargo.exe check --message-format json --workspace --all-targets -Z unstable-options --keep-going
    Checking cfg-if v1.0.0
    Checking log v0.4.20
    Checking winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu v0.4.0
    Checking memchr v2.7.1
    Checking futures-core v0.3.30
    Checking winapi v0.3.9
    Checking pin-project-lite v0.2.13
    Checking smallvec v1.11.2
    Checking futures-sink v0.3.30
    Checking scopeguard v1.2.0
    Checking slab v0.4.9
Checking actix-cors v0.5.4
    Checking anyhow v1.0.79
    Checking uuid v1.6.1
    Checking colored v2.1.0
    Checking dotenv v0.15.0
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5: zstd/lib/common\debug.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5: zstd/lib/common\debug.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5:  /* ******************************************************************
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5:  /* ******************************************************************
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5:  
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5:  
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5: zstd/lib/common\fse_decompress.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5: zstd/lib/common\fse_decompress.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5:  /* ******************************************************************
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5:  
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5: zstd/lib/common\entropy_common.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5: zstd/lib/common\entropy_common.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5:  /* ******************************************************************
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5:  
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5: zstd/lib/common\error_private.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5: zstd/lib/common\error_private.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5:  /*
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5:  /*
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5:  
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5: ToolExecError: Command "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "zstd/lib/" "-I" "zstd/lib/common" "-I" "zstd/lib/legacy" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM=" "-DZSTD_LIB_DEPRECATED=0" "-DXXH_PRIVATE_API=" "-DZSTDLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZDICTLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTDERRORLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT=1" "-o" "C:\\Users\\bolingo\\RustroverProjects\\rest-api-with-actix-and-jwt\\target\\debug\\build\\zstd-sys-5105d09a8fced19b\\out\\zstd/lib/common\\debug.o" "-c" "zstd/lib/common\\debug.c" with args "gcc.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).running: "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "zstd/lib/" "-I" "zstd/lib/common" "-I" "zstd/lib/legacy" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM=" "-DZSTD_LIB_DEPRECATED=0" "-DXXH_PRIVATE_API=" "-DZSTDLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZDICTLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTDERRORLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT=1" "-o" "C:\\Users\\bolingo\\RustroverProjects\\rest-api-with-actix-and-jwt\\target\\debug\\build\\zstd-sys-5105d09a8fced19b\\out\\zstd/lib/common\\pool.o" "-c" "zstd/lib/common\\pool.c"
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5: ToolExecError: Command "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "zstd/lib/" "-I" "zstd/lib/common" "-I" "zstd/lib/legacy" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM=" "-DZSTD_LIB_DEPRECATED=0" "-DXXH_PRIVATE_API=" "-DZSTDLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZDICTLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTDERRORLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT=1" "-o" "C:\\Users\\bolingo\\RustroverProjects\\rest-api-with-actix-and-jwt\\target\\debug\\build\\zstd-sys-5105d09a8fced19b\\out\\zstd/lib/common\\debug.o" "-c" "zstd/lib/common\\debug.c" with args "gcc.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).running: "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "zstd/lib/" "-I" "zstd/lib/common" "-I" "zstd/lib/legacy" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM=" "-DZSTD_LIB_DEPRECATED=0" "-DXXH_PRIVATE_API=" "-DZSTDLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZDICTLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTDERRORLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT=1" "-o" "C:\\Users\\bolingo\\RustroverProjects\\rest-api-with-actix-and-jwt\\target\\debug\\build\\zstd-sys-5105d09a8fced19b\\out\\zstd/lib/common\\pool.o" "-c" "zstd/lib/common\\pool.c"
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5: ToolExecError: Command "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "zstd/lib/" "-I" "zstd/lib/common" "-I" "zstd/lib/legacy" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM=" "-DZSTD_LIB_DEPRECATED=0" "-DXXH_PRIVATE_API=" "-DZSTDLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZDICTLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTDERRORLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT=1" "-o" "C:\\Users\\bolingo\\RustroverProjects\\rest-api-with-actix-and-jwt\\target\\debug\\build\\zstd-sys-5105d09a8fced19b\\out\\zstd/lib/common\\entropy_common.o" "-c" "zstd/lib/common\\entropy_common.c" with args "gcc.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5: ToolExecError: Command "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "zstd/lib/" "-I" "zstd/lib/common" "-I" "zstd/lib/legacy" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM=" "-DZSTD_LIB_DEPRECATED=0" "-DXXH_PRIVATE_API=" "-DZSTDLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZDICTLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTDERRORLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT=1" "-o" "C:\\Users\\bolingo\\RustroverProjects\\rest-api-with-actix-and-jwt\\target\\debug\\build\\zstd-sys-5105d09a8fced19b\\out\\zstd/lib/common\\entropy_common.o" "-c" "zstd/lib/common\\entropy_common.c" with args "gcc.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5: ToolExecError: Command "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "zstd/lib/" "-I" "zstd/lib/common" "-I" "zstd/lib/legacy" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM=" "-DZSTD_LIB_DEPRECATED=0" "-DXXH_PRIVATE_API=" "-DZSTDLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZDICTLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTDERRORLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT=1" "-o" "C:\\Users\\bolingo\\RustroverProjects\\rest-api-with-actix-and-jwt\\target\\debug\\build\\zstd-sys-5105d09a8fced19b\\out\\zstd/lib/common\\error_private.o" "-c" "zstd/lib/common\\error_private.c" with args "gcc.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5: ToolExecError: Command "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "zstd/lib/" "-I" "zstd/lib/common" "-I" "zstd/lib/legacy" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM=" "-DZSTD_LIB_DEPRECATED=0" "-DXXH_PRIVATE_API=" "-DZSTDLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZDICTLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTDERRORLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT=1" "-o" "C:\\Users\\bolingo\\RustroverProjects\\rest-api-with-actix-and-jwt\\target\\debug\\build\\zstd-sys-5105d09a8fced19b\\out\\zstd/lib/common\\error_private.o" "-c" "zstd/lib/common\\error_private.c" with args "gcc.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5: ToolExecError: Command "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "zstd/lib/" "-I" "zstd/lib/common" "-I" "zstd/lib/legacy" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM=" "-DZSTD_LIB_DEPRECATED=0" "-DXXH_PRIVATE_API=" "-DZSTDLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZDICTLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTDERRORLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT=1" "-o" "C:\\Users\\bolingo\\RustroverProjects\\rest-api-with-actix-and-jwt\\target\\debug\\build\\zstd-sys-5105d09a8fced19b\\out\\zstd/lib/common\\fse_decompress.o" "-c" "zstd/lib/common\\fse_decompress.c" with args "gcc.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).running: "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "zstd/lib/" "-I" "zstd/lib/common" "-I" "zstd/lib/legacy" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM=" "-DZSTD_LIB_DEPRECATED=0" "-DXXH_PRIVATE_API=" "-DZSTDLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZDICTLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTDERRORLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT=1" "-o" "C:\\Users\\bolingo\\RustroverProjects\\rest-api-with-actix-and-jwt\\target\\debug\\build\\zstd-sys-5105d09a8fced19b\\out\\zstd/lib/common\\threading.o" "-c" "zstd/lib/common\\threading.c"
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5: ToolExecError: Command "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "zstd/lib/" "-I" "zstd/lib/common" "-I" "zstd/lib/legacy" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM=" "-DZSTD_LIB_DEPRECATED=0" "-DXXH_PRIVATE_API=" "-DZSTDLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZDICTLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTDERRORLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT=1" "-o" "C:\\Users\\bolingo\\RustroverProjects\\rest-api-with-actix-and-jwt\\target\\debug\\build\\zstd-sys-5105d09a8fced19b\\out\\zstd/lib/common\\fse_decompress.o" "-c" "zstd/lib/common\\fse_decompress.c" with args "gcc.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).running: "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "zstd/lib/" "-I" "zstd/lib/common" "-I" "zstd/lib/legacy" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM=" "-DZSTD_LIB_DEPRECATED=0" "-DXXH_PRIVATE_API=" "-DZSTDLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZDICTLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTDERRORLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT=1" "-o" "C:\\Users\\bolingo\\RustroverProjects\\rest-api-with-actix-and-jwt\\target\\debug\\build\\zstd-sys-5105d09a8fced19b\\out\\zstd/lib/common\\threading.o" "-c" "zstd/lib/common\\threading.c"
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5: zstd/lib/common\threading.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5: zstd/lib/common\threading.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5:  /**
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5:  /**
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5:  
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5: ToolExecError: Command "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "zstd/lib/" "-I" "zstd/lib/common" "-I" "zstd/lib/legacy" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM=" "-DZSTD_LIB_DEPRECATED=0" "-DXXH_PRIVATE_API=" "-DZSTDLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZDICTLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTDERRORLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT=1" "-o" "C:\\Users\\bolingo\\RustroverProjects\\rest-api-with-actix-and-jwt\\target\\debug\\build\\zstd-sys-5105d09a8fced19b\\out\\zstd/lib/legacy\\zstd_v07.o" "-c" "zstd/lib/legacy\\zstd_v07.c" with args "gcc.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).
warning: zstd-sys@2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5: ToolExecError: Command "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "zstd/lib/" "-I" "zstd/lib/common" "-I" "zstd/lib/legacy" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM=" "-DZSTD_LIB_DEPRECATED=0" "-DXXH_PRIVATE_API=" "-DZSTDLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZDICTLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTDERRORLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT=1" "-o" "C:\\Users\\bolingo\\RustroverProjects\\rest-api-with-actix-and-jwt\\target\\debug\\build\\zstd-sys-5105d09a8fced19b\\out\\zstd/lib/legacy\\zstd_v07.o" "-c" "zstd/lib/legacy\\zstd_v07.c" with args "gcc.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).
error: failed to run custom build command for `zstd-sys v2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5`
error: failed to run custom build command for `zstd-sys v2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5`
note: To improve backtraces for build dependencies, set the CARGO_PROFILE_DEV_BUILD_OVERRIDE_DEBUG=true environment variable to enable debug information generation.
Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\bolingo\RustroverProjects\rest-api-with-actix-and-jwt\target\debug\build\zstd-sys-dc50d7da80f6697b\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
  --- stdout

cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ZSTD_SYS_USE_PKG_CONFIG
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-gnu")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-gnu")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
  CC_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu
  CC_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CC
  HOST_CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
  CC = None
cargo:warning=ToolExecError: Command "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "zstd/lib/" "-I" "zstd/lib/common" "-I" "zstd/lib/legacy" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM=" "-DZSTD_LIB_DEPRECATED=0" "-DXXH_PRIVATE_API=" "-DZSTDLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZDICTLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTDERRORLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT=1" "-o" "C:\\Users\\bolingo\\RustroverProjects\\rest-api-with-actix-and-jwt\\target\\debug\\build\\zstd-sys-5105d09a8fced19b\\out\\zstd/lib/legacy\\zstd_v05.o" "-c" "zstd/lib/legacy\\zstd_v05.c" with args "gcc.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).
  exit code: 1
  cargo:warning=ToolExecError: Command "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "zstd/lib/" "-I" "zstd/lib/common" "-I" "zstd/lib/legacy" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM=" "-DZSTD_LIB_DEPRECATED=0" "-DXXH_PRIVATE_API=" "-DZSTDLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZDICTLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTDERRORLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT=1" "-o" "C:\\Users\\bolingo\\RustroverProjects\\rest-api-with-actix-and-jwt\\target\\debug\\build\\zstd-sys-5105d09a8fced19b\\out\\zstd/lib/legacy\\zstd_v06.o" "-c" "zstd/lib/legacy\\zstd_v06.c" with args "gcc.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).cargo:warning=zstd/lib/legacy\zstd_v07.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
  cargo:warning= /*
  cargo:warning= 
  exit code: 1
  cargo:warning=ToolExecError: Command "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "zstd/lib/" "-I" "zstd/lib/common" "-I" "zstd/lib/legacy" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM=" "-DZSTD_LIB_DEPRECATED=0" "-DXXH_PRIVATE_API=" "-DZSTDLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZDICTLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTDERRORLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT=1" "-o" "C:\\Users\\bolingo\\RustroverProjects\\rest-api-with-actix-and-jwt\\target\\debug\\build\\zstd-sys-5105d09a8fced19b\\out\\zstd/lib/legacy\\zstd_v07.o" "-c" "zstd/lib/legacy\\zstd_v07.c" with args "gcc.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).
  --- stderr
  error occurred: Command "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "zstd/lib/" "-I" "zstd/lib/common" "-I" "zstd/lib/legacy" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM=" "-DZSTD_LIB_DEPRECATED=0" "-DXXH_PRIVATE_API=" "-DZSTDLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZDICTLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTDERRORLIB_VISIBILITY=" "-DZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT=1" "-o" "C:\\Users\\bolingo\\RustroverProjects\\rest-api-with-actix-and-jwt\\target\\debug\\build\\zstd-sys-5105d09a8fced19b\\out\\zstd/lib/legacy\\zstd_v07.o" "-c" "zstd/lib/legacy\\zstd_v07.c" with args "gcc.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).
```

I attempted to resolve the issue by adding `zstd = "0.13.0"` and `zstd-sys = "2.0.9+zstd.1.5.5"`, but the problem persists. Seeking guidance on resolving this compatibility issue.

Comment: You will need to provide the full error output since it will describe *why* it failed. What makes you think its a "compatibility" issue?

Comment: Sorry ! I'm not sure if it's a "compatibility" issue, but when I switch the "actix web" version to "3.3.3," for instance, the compilation is successfu

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not an image.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) The image doesn't event include everything. Edit your post with the full output in a code block.

Comment: It's fine. The post has been edited!

Answer (score -1):

Appreciate your help. I managed to resolve the issue by adjusting the Actix-Web version as follows:

```
actix-web = { version = "4.4.0", default-features = false }
```

I simply set the "default-features" to false.